# Windows update error code : 80244004

Tags: windows-7, updates, windows-update

I am using Windows 7 and ESET SMART SECURITY 5 .

Today I wanted to update my computer using Windows Update but it does give me error :

> Error(s) found:
>
> Code 80244004         Windows Update encountered an unknown error.

My System Info :

Sony Vaio EA2gfx , Ram : 4GB DDR2
, CPU: Intel Core i 5

I checkd out this links but they didn't help :
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/while-updating-i-am-getting-the-error-code/0b9b756c-5b6e-4571-838e-f90c48a4e00c

https://www.calguns.net/calgunforum/showthread.php?t=583860

http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/235807-windows-update-error-80244004-a.html

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Are you running Eset or Malwarebytes??

Comment: You might try this: [Troubleshoot common installation issues in Windows Update, Microsoft Update, and Windows Server Update Services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906602)

Comment: Yes I'm using ESET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem solved by changing some settings in ESET SMART SECURITY :
In ESET I went to :

`Setup > Enter advanced setup... > Web and email > Web access and antiphishing protection > HTTP, HTTPS`

then in `HTTPS scanner setup` tab and in `HTTPS filtering mode` tab :

check the `Do not use HTTPS protocol checking`

Then the problem solves

Answer (score 2):

I was not totally comfortable with [the Eset change suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/439725/windows-update-error-code-80244004/440043#440043), so I called Eset. They did not recommend this change - said they had another call on this and were looking at solutions.

However, I mentioned another problem I have been having accessing HTTPS sites in Firefox - I thought they were Firefox Tab-Group issues. Amazingly, the Eset person said they have a fix for this one and it fixed my Windows update problem:

First, close all apps that might be accessing the web using HTTPS.

1. Open Eset Smart Security (I have 5.2.9.1 and this all may have started when I upgraded recently).
2. Push <kbd>F5</kbd> key
3. Expand Web and Email
4. Expand Protocol Filtering
5. Click on SSL
6. Select Do not scan SSL protocol
7. Click OK
8. Try Microsoft Update again - should work - mine did!

Comment: This just repeats what the accepted answer says.